# Deeper level LINQ query in a lambda expression

Tags: linq, lambda

I would like to get those employees who have a phone number == "666666" using a LINQ query.

**These are the class definitions:**

```
public class Employees
{
    public List<Phones> Phones{get;set}
}
public class Phones
{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string Number{get;set;}
}
```

**This is my query (my doubt indicated as ???):**

```
var employees= data.GetEmployees()
                   .Where(e=> e.Phones ???i need to navigate a level below phones ???)
                   .Select(e => new Employee() 
                   {     
                        Id=e.Id,
                        Name=e.Name 
                   });
```

My problem is I don't know how to go a deeper level in this LINQ expression, because in `e=>e...` I have access to `Phones` as an `IEnumerable` but I would like to navigate to `Phone`'s properties.

Comment: Are you trying to call the devil? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use nested LINQ queries.  In this case you should look at the `Any` method.

```
var employees= data
  .GetEmployees()
  .Where(e => e.Phones.Any(p => p.Number == "666666"))
  .Select(e => new Employee() {
    Id = e.Id,
    Name = e.Name
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Best answer after 10 minutes :-))

Answer (score 3):

The parameter passed to the where method is merely a function that returns true or false for each given element, all methods (including LINQ ones (subject to accessing ref/out params etc)) can still be called within it:

```
var employees= data.GetEmployees()
               .Where(e => e.Phones.Any(p => p.Number == "666666"))
               .Select(e => new Employee() 
               {     
                    Id=e.Id,
                    Name=e.Name 
               });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var employees= data.GetEmployees()
               .Where(e=> e.Phones.Contains(x=>x.Number == "666666"))
               .Select(e => new Employee() 
               {     
                    Id=e.Id,
                    Name=e.Name 
               });
```